# Configuring apache with SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to configure apache with SSL. I am facing 2 issues:

1) If typed www.example.com it doesn't redirect to https://example.com (Though, i have written the rewrite rule).

2)And while running https://example.com it shows unauthorized label with https.

Here is a reference of how my apache configuration file look a like.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerName  example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [L,R=301]

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile PATH_TO_CERTIFICATE_FILE
  SSLCertificateKeyFile PATH_TO_PERMISSION_KEY_FILE
  SSLCertificateChainFile PATH_TO_GD_BUNDLE_CERTIFICATE_FILE

</VirtualHost>
```

I have enabled my mod_ssl.

I would highly appreciate if anyone can throw some light on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're looking to redirect http://www.example.com to https://example.com.  In order to do that you'll need to have a VirtualHost instance listening on port 80 and put the rewrite rules there.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. The Second problem still persists. I checked domain SSL certificate which is fine. The problem i think here is that https://example.com loads others resources like JS and CSS(say: http://static.example.com/) which is not running over https. So, it gives a warning. What do you think? is this could be the issue?

Comment: @aatifh - Yes. If current page uses HTTPS then `static.example.com` site has to be on HTTPS as well. For that you would need to set it up on another IP:port combination .. or obtain wildcard SSL certificate that will cover both of these domains. Check this link: [Is it really a security problem to have non secure assets on an ssl page?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15605/is-it-really-a-security-problem-to-have-non-secure-assets-on-an-ssl-page)